# inserted table role in instead of insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a view based upon 2 tables, I have written an `instead of insert` trigger to insert into that view:

```
Create trigger tr_vWEmployeeDetails_InsteadOfInsert
on vWEmployeeDetails
Instead Of Insert
as
Begin
    Declare @DeptId int

    Select @DeptId = DeptId 
    from tblDepartment 
    join inserted on inserted.DeptName = tblDepartment.DeptName

    if(@DeptId is null)
    Begin
        Raiserror('Invalid Department Name. Statement terminated', 16, 1)
        return
    End

    Insert into tblEmployee(Id, Name, Gender, DepartmentId)
        Select Id, Name, Gender, @DeptId
        from inserted
End
```

The above code works fine, but I want to know that the insert statement to the view doesn't work, instead the trigger works, then from where do we get values in the 'inserted' magic table.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

From the relevant [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> DML trigger statements use two special tables: the deleted table and the inserted tables. SQL Server automatically creates and manages these tables. You can use these temporary, memory-resident tables to test the effects of certain data modifications and to set conditions for DML trigger actions. You cannot directly modify the data in the tables or perform data definition language (DDL) operations on the tables, such as CREATE INDEX.

The insert on the view is blocked by the use of the `instead of` trigger - That's literally the meaning of "instead of".

**Please note** that your trigger code will fail if an insert statement to the view will try to insert multiple records. The reason for this is that in SQL Server, triggers are raised per statement, and not per row. The following code that is specified in the beginning of the trigger

```
Declare @DeptId int
Select @DeptId = DeptId 
from tblDepartment 
join inserted
on inserted.DeptName = tblDepartment.DeptName
```

Will fail once the inserted table will have multiple rows that matches the on clause if the join.

Triggers in SQL Server must **always** be written to handle multiple rows in the inserted / deleted table.